# Can't use a variable from a superclass in method in subclass

Tags: java

I have an issue using a variable from a superclass. See the code below. In ConncetionMap (final int n), I can successfully use the variable n from the superclass, but in the overridden Test() method, that variable n suddenly is not recognized anymore. How can I keep using the variable n there?

I thought that if ConncetionMap is public, I should be able to access n from other places in the same class.

```
public abstract class Connection {
    public Connection(final int n) {
    }

    public abstract int Test();
}


public class ConnectionMap extends Connection {

    public ConnectionMap (final int n) {
        super(n);

        //Here, n is recognized from the superclass and it simply works
        if (n < 0) {  
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int Test() {
        int c = n; //This is an example usage of n, and here n is not recognized anymore.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`n` is an argument of the constructor. An argument, like a local variable, is scoped to the method/constructor. So it's only visible from the constructor. This doesn't have much to do with superclasses, BTW. Just with variable scope.

If the superclass doesn't provide any way to get its value (for example, using a protected or public `getN()` method), then you need to store it into a field in a subclass to be able to access it from another method:

```
public class ConnectionMap extends Connection {

    private int n;

    public ConnectionMap (final int n) {
        super(n);

        //Here, n is recognized from the superclass and it simply works
        if (n < 0) {  
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error.");
        }
        this.n = n;
    }

    @Override
    public int test() {
        int c = this.n;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: getN would be unuseful, as `n` **is not recorded, dropped in the constructor of Connection**

Comment: you said "getN" in parent

Comment: I assume the posted code has been simplified. I don't see why the superclass constructor would take an argument that it doesn't use at all. The test() method wouldn't compile either, but I also assume that the reason is that the OP removed the irrelevant stuff. A getN() method, returning the n passed to the constructor, would serve the same purpose as the public n attribute that you added in your answer. I wouldn't advise using public attributes BTW.

Comment: I did simplify the code and remove the irrelevant stuff. The test() method was simply to demonstrate that the variable n isn't recognized there.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `n` as a local variable (parameter) in your constructor, so it's not available outside its scope. Try this:

```
public abstract class Connection {
    public final int n;
    public Connection(final int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }

    public abstract int Test();
}


public class ConnectionMap extends Connection {

    public ConnectionMap (final int n) {
        super(n);

        //Here, n is recognized from the superclass and it simply works
        if (n < 0) {  
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int Test() {
        int c = n; //This is an example usage of n, and here n is not recognized anymore.
    }
}
```

Here, `n` in constructor is passed to `n` in your object. As `public` >= `protected`, `n` is inherited from Connection to ConnectionMap, so it can be used in `Test()`.